# Is there a to access PageModel properties inside razor page, without Model prefix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Let's consider a simple example:

```
public class ContactModel : PageModel
{
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    
    public OnGet()
    {
        Contact = new Contact
        {
            Name = "John"
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
@page
@model ContactModel

<div>@Model.Contact.Name</div>
```

As you can see, we are force to use `Model` in our razor pages. This gets really ugly and reduces code readability.

Also in real-world applications, it's a boilerplate word, that needs to be repeated again and again.

Is there a way to not write it?

Answer (score 2):

> This gets really ugly and reduces code readability.

That's kinda subjective; I don't mind it because it actively declares "this data is coming from the model rather than a temp variable"

> Is there a way to not write it?

I suppose you could alias it?

```
@model SomeModel
@{
  var m = Model;
}

<h1>Hello @m.Name</h1>
```

Or alias into it

```
@model SomeModel
@{
  var name = Model.Name;
}

<h1>Hello @name</h1>
```

If you have a lot of them to do, tuple deconstruction might shorten it a bit for you

```
@model SomeModel
@{
  var (name, age) = (Model.Name, Model.Age);
}

<h1>Hello @name</h1>
You turned @age today!
```

If the model returned all its info as a tuple it could be deconstructed by eg `var (name, age, city) = Model.AllInfoAsTuple`

Answer (score 1):

`ContactModel` is a PageModel,and  `public Contact Contact { get; set; }` is the property of `ContactModel`.You use `@model ContactModel` in your page,so if you want to show it with `@xxx`,you need to use `@Model.ContactModel.Name`.

But if you want to bind the data with `input`,you can try [tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0),so that you don't need to use `@Model`.Here is a sample:

```
<input asp-for="ContactModel.Name" />
```